# Jquery - get element closest to clicked button in container

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I use php to fetch data from a mongodb database and display it as html elements . With jquery I want to click on a button on each item I have and get the element title of the clicked item  and console.log it.

This is my product container with the created elements .

```
<div class="category__container">
          <div class="category__center">
            <?php 
                //get products and display them as html 
                $cursor = $collection->find();
              foreach ($cursor as $doc){
                echo 
                  " <div class= 'product category__products'>
                        <div class='product__header'>
                          <img src = ".$doc["image"]." />
                        </div>  
                        <div class= 'product__footer'>
                          <h2> ".$doc["title"]." </h2>                              
                          <div class= 'product__price'>
                              <h4> $".$doc["price"]." </h4>
                          </div>
                          <button type='button' class='product__btn'>Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  ";

              }  

            ?>
          </div>
        </div>
```

My jquery event on document ready  :

```
$('.category__center').on('click' , '.product__btn' ,(e)=>{
  //this is where I want to get the <h2> title from '.product__footer'
  

})
```

I would appreciate your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `closest(".product__footer").find("h2")` to get `h2` tag value.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.category__center').on('click', '.product__btn', (e) => {
  //get closest product footer then h2 text
  console.log($(e.target).closest(".product__footer").find("h2").text())
  console.log($(e.target).closest(".product").find('img').attr('src'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category__container">
  <div class="category__center">
    <div class='product category__products'>
      <div class='product__header'>
        <img src="abc.png" />
      </div>
      <div class='product__footer'>
        <h2> Abs12</h2>
        <div class='product__price'>
          <h4>123 </h4>
        </div>
        <button type='button' class='product__btn'>Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product category__products'>
      <div class='product__header'>
        <img src="deded.png" />
      </div>
      <div class='product__footer'>
        <h2> Abcd </h2>
        <div class='product__price'>
          <h4>12 </h4>
        </div>
        <button type='button' class='product__btn'>Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have just one problem . If I try   var pic =  $(e.target).closest(".product__header").find("img").attr('src').text(); i cannot find the image src and console.log it as a a string I get undefined

Comment: Updated my code have a look :) `product__header` is siblings of `product__footer` that's why that doesn't work . Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much . Isn't it a better practice to use .product instead of .product__footer in every variable then ?

Comment: That depend on you which part you need to get .I have shown you just one way to do above things there are many other ways as well to get same result . Please go through that link will surely help you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom attribute with each product__btn like -

```html
<button type='button' class='product__btn' data-product='".$doc["title"]."'>Add To Cart</button>
```

Now in the click event in jQuery, use -

```js
$('.category__center').on('click' , '.product__btn' ,(e)=>{
  var productName = $(this).attr('data-product');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click",".product__btn", function(){
   let title = $(this).closest(".product__footer").find("> h2").text().trim();
   console.log(title);
});
```